# Hibernate one to many with annotations

Tags: hibernate

Hi guy's i'm very new to hibernate and i have to use annotations also.I have two POJO classes one is having the fields id1,description in which id is the primary key .I have another table whose fields are id,id1(foreign key),control,value.
I have to design a foreign key relationship between these two having one-to many relationship.Can anybody help me.

Please help how to create a relationships between these two classes.

Thank you,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy [this](http://tadtech.blogspot.com/2007/09/hibernate-annotation-many-to-many.html)
It shows exactly what you want, however there should be plenty of examples on stackoverflow too; just try to use the "search"